# What is a model and how is it designed?

Tags: terminology, models

I read these things on the internet like

> My model determines the future scope..."

or

> My model gives accurate readings about what the score would be..."

What are these models? How are they designed?

Comment: Welcome to AI!  It would be helpful if you could provide more context, ideally links to where you read it.

Comment: @DukeZhou This question lacks artificial intelligence context

Answer (score 2):

A model is exactly what the name suggests.  A simplified representation of a solution to a real life problem.

For example, if you think of a simple formula for a falling object you may not take into account real life variables such as the imperfections on the surface of the object, atmospheric conditions, the exact composition of the air the object is falling through and how it may affect friction.  you just use a simple model to "model" the fall and get a reasonably accurate result.  its a model, it doesnt have all the details.  just like a model car wouldnt have all the details of a real car.

Here's a good read to get you started:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_model

Comment: The word "model" may not suggest anything, if you don't know the meaning of the word.

Comment: "A simplified representation of a solution to a real life problem.": why is a model a representation of a _solution_? Are you sure?

Comment: In the context of what the poster is asking it is a solution or a problem or just anything.  I tried to explain in the rest of the post but it doesnt matter as I have a feeling this whole thread will be marked off-topic soon.

Comment: These links might strengthen this answer: [Model-based reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-based_reasoning), [Bayesian Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network), and [Statistical Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model)